# Oracle restore backup on other server

Tags: oracle, restore, rman

I have following situation:
One server with Oracle has to be backed up and recovered on other Oracle server.
Second Oracle DB has the same user/schemas, but with a different older data.

I intend to update the data on it by backup from first DB and restoring it on the secondary DB.

I've ran a backup with following **rman** command:

```
connect target
run {
allocate channel ch1 device type disk format '\\192.168.1.40\Archive\ARC%u_%c;
backup database ;
release channel ch1;
}
```

Now I have two files created on a network share.

On the other server I intended to run following command:

```
RMAN> run {
2>   allocate channel ch1 type disk format '\\192.168.1.40\Archive\ARC%u_%c';
4>   restore database;
5>   recover database;
6>   release channel t1;
7> }
```

But it fails with error

```
RMAN-03002: failure of restore command at 02/06/2014 14:24:45
ORA-01180: can not create datafile 1
ORA-01110: data file 1: 'C:\ORACLE\MUR\DATA1\SYSTEM_1\SYSTEM.DATA1'
```

Can you suggest what should I do in this case? How the restoration is done on Oracle?

## Answer Found:

I found the answer. 
Backup location should be populated. 
I copied backup to a local drive F: and run following command in RMAN:

```
rman> catalog start with 'F:\backup\';
```

It has responded with

```
searching for all files that match the pattern F:\

List of Files Unknown to the Database
=====================================

File Name: F:\backup\ARC0AOVT8H9_1
File Name: F:\backup\ARC0BOVTGN3_1

Do you really want to catalog the above files (enter YES or NO)? yes
cataloging files...
cataloging done

List of Cataloged Files
=======================
File Name: F:\backup\ARC0AOVT8H9_1
File Name: F:\backup\ARC0BOVTGN3_1
```

After that I run

```
RMAN> run {
2>   allocate channel t1 type disk format 'F:\backup\ARC%u_%c';
3>   restore database;
4>   recover database;
5>   release channel t1;
6> }
```

And recovery started

Comment: I found the answer. Backup location should be populated.
I copied backup to a local drive F: and run following command in RMAN:
catalog start with 'F:\backup\';